# Google API for Label and Filter Creation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

My business is on Google for email.  I want to use a nightly script to push out a Label and a Filter to all my users.

What I would like to do is to create a Label for all my users called "My Tickets" and a filter for all email with "Ticket assigned to you" in the subject line.

I am able to create the label using the API and I am able to create the filter using the API; however, creating the filter requires the label ID which would be created in step 1, but it is not known at the time step 2 would occur.

The API only allows for the label_ID and not the name.  In order for me to write this script I need some way to know what the label ID is after it is created and then pass it to the next part of the script to create the filter.

I am not sure how to do this.  If there was a way to do the create Label, then find label_id I think I could do it, but you can't use the API to show you what a label_ID is by it's name.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

Comment: Check this [`GmailLabel`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label) in the Apps Script documentation if it can help you. You will learn here all the possible way that you can do with the Gmail labels. It will also show you some sample code on how to use the different method using GmailLabel.